# Converting birth date to current year

Tags: sql, date

My employee file has the birthdate year which will not presently allow me to create a calendar in the current year that will show that birthdate unless I convert the year to the present year.  How can I make that conversion?
I have tried creating temp fields for the Month & day and then tried to concatenate the year month day to get back to a date value.

```
  Declare @Year1 int = 2019;
  select dateadd(@year1,[year]-1900,dateadd(month(birthdate), 
  [month]-1,dateadd(day(birthdate),[day]-1,0)))
  from vhemployee where employerid<>1 and status=1
```

Comment: Please add the tag for the dbms do you use

Answer (score 3):

You're over-thinking it.

Use `DATEDIFF` to find the number of years since the `birthdate`, then use `DATEADD` to add that number of years to the `birthdate` to get the date of their birthday this year.

The CTE here just has three random dates in the past that represent `birthdate` values. The query you need follows the CTE.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT CAST(v.BD AS DATE) AS birthdate
  FROM (VALUES ('19641210'),('19830518'),('20010911')) AS v(BD)
)
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,cte.birthdate,GETDATE()),cte.birthdate) AS tybd
FROM cte
```

Results:

```
+------------+
|    tybd    |
+------------+
| 2019-12-10 |
| 2019-05-18 |
| 2019-09-11 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it is using the DateFromParts function in SQL Server.

Declare @Year Int = 2019

Select DATEFROMPARTS (@Year, Month(BirthDate), Day(BirthDate))
From VhEmployee 
Where Employerid <> 1 
AND [Status] = 1

Comment: declare @year int = 2019
select datefromparts(@year,month(birthdate).day(birthdate)), birthdate,* 
from vhemployee where employerid<>1 and status=1     results in this error  Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The datefromparts function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: I correct the period ahead of day to a comma and received this error   Msg 289, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

Comment: I believe your table has the non-date values. Those're causing issues.
**Try This:**
`declare @year int = 2019 select datefromparts(@year,month(birthdate), day(birthdate)), birthdate,* from vhemployee where employerid<>1 and status=1 AND ISDATE(birthdate) = 1`

Comment: I am wondering if I have some birth dates that are 02-29 where converting to 2019 is an invalid date.

Comment: Yes, there are some dates with 02-29. You need to write SQL something like this.
`declare @year int = 2019 select CASE WHEN Month(BirthDate) = 2 AND Day(BirthDate) = 29 THEN Null ELSE datefromparts(@year,month(birthdate), day(birthdate)) END As ThisYearDate, birthdate,* from vhemployee where employerid<>1 and status=1 AND ISDATE(birthdate) = 1`

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse or anything, but if you just use the built in date functions, they handle thing like February 29 elegantly without forcing you to write a bunch of extraneous code.